# Scala mixin to class instance

Tags: scala, mixins

Is it possible in Scala to make some mixin to class instance?

Eg: I have some MyClass instance `var x = new MyClass` and I want to extend it on some method or trait without copying it.

**[Edit:]**
I'm looking the way to extend `x` after it has been instantiated.
So, for example in a function method, which gets `x` as a parameter.

**[What is behind]**
I've just wonder if there is some magic with implicit objects and Manifest to achieve the typeclass pattern without explicit call implicit object (like in Haskell).
But only for single object.

I know if is artificial, but I've just wonder if it's possible because of lot of magic with mixing Scalas features.

Comment: Do you mean mix in additional methods on `x` *after* it has been instantiated, or *during* instantiation?

Comment: after it has been instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. You may look at using the [`Dynamic` trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Dynamic) or Kevin Wright's [auto-proxy plugin](https://github.com/kevinwright/Autoproxy-Lite), but, either way, you'll create a *new* object that also answers to the original one's method through proxying.

Answer (score 3):

you mean like:

```
val x = new MyClass with MyTrait
```

Yes you can. Just overriding methods obviously can be:

```
val x = new MyClass { 
  override def myMethod = { my implementation }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but look an edit in the question post

Comment: thanks for the additional info, it should have been in the initial question as it seems to be a pretty important one :-) i am now curious, why do you need to add a trait after the object has been instantiated? Can you please share some code sample to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry - when i was writing I thought it's clear, but 2 days later after reading your answer I've realized it is not.
The question is just for interest, I've put more info in the question post.

Comment: well if you have a valid use case, you could put it up for discussion on [the scala-debate](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-debate)

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this problem as I was wondering the same thing...

```
case class Person(name: String)
val dave = Person("Dave")
val joe  = Person("Joe")

trait Dog { val dogName: String }
val spot = new Dog { val dogName = "Spot" }

implicit def daveHasDog(p: dave.type) = spot

dave.dogName //"Spot"
joe.dogName  //error: value dogName is not a member of Person
```

So now the `dave` *instance* (rather than all instances of class Person) behaves like a `Person with Dog`, at long as the implicit is in scope.

This will work in most cases, except where your trait has self-types.