# Can we use the singleton .type as a type parameter?

Tags: scala, types, type-parameter

I was cobbling together an answer to this question: [Scala mixin to class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949819/scala-mixin-to-class-instance/10199639#10199639), where I showed a way of "mixing-in" another trait or class instance to an existing instance:

```
case class Person(name: String)
val dave = Person("Dave")
val joe  = Person("Joe")

trait Dog { val dogName: String }
val spot = new Dog { val dogName = "Spot" }

implicit def daveHasDog(p: dave.type) = spot

dave.dogName //"Spot"
joe.dogName  //error: value dogName is not a member of Person
```

So after the local implicit def, `dave` can effectively be used as a `Person with Dog`. My question is, if we wanted to define a method that takes a `Person` instance only where the `Person` has a `Dog`, how do we do it?

I can define a method such as

```
def showDog(pd: Person with Dog) = pd.name + " shows " + pd.dogName
```

however this is no good for `dave` since he is still just a `Person`, despite his implicit transformation abilities.

I tried defining

```
trait Dog [T] { val dogName: String }
val spot = new Dog [dave.type] { val dogName = "Spot" }
def showDog(p: Person)(implicit dog: Dog[p.type]) = ...
```

but this is not legal, giving `error: illegal dependent method type`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compile with `-Ydependent-method-types`, your original code will work with this definition of `showDog`:

```
scala> def showDog(p: Person)(implicit ev: p.type => Dog) = p.name + " shows " + p.dogName
showDog: (p: Person)(implicit ev: p.type => Dog)java.lang.String

scala> showDog(dave)
res1: java.lang.String = Dave shows Spot
```

Comment: Just to be clear: this requires dependent types because the *type* of `ev` is *dependent* on the *value* `p`. I'm quite surprised and impressed that Scala even has a compiler option for this.

Comment: @Dan Would be even better if it were enabled by default.

Comment: @ziggystar: I think this is going to be enabled in 2.10. (In fact the macro and reflection system relies on it.)

Comment: @Debilski it's already enabled in the latest 2.10 milestones.